# Show that $[0, \omega_1[$ is not $\sigma$-compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, ordinals

Consider the set $\Omega$ of countable ordinals and let $\omega_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal, $\Omega^*= \Omega \cup \{\omega_1\}$ and equip $\Omega^*$ with the order topology.

I know that $\Omega^*$ is compact Hausdorff. I'm asked to show that
$\Omega$ is an open subset of $\Omega^*$ that is not $\sigma$-compact.

**Attempt**: Clearly the complement $\Omega^* \setminus \Omega = \{\omega_1\}$ is closed so $\Omega$ is open. Suppose to the contrary that $\Omega$ is $\sigma$-compact (in the relative topology). Then since $\Omega$ itself is locally compact Hausdorff this is equivalent with saying that $\Omega$ is Lindelöf. However, $$\{ \left[0,a\right[ : a < \omega_1\}$$ is an open cover of $\Omega$ consisting of countable sets so $\Omega$ has no countable subcover because $\Omega= \omega_1$ is uncountable and the countable union of countable sets is countable. This is a contradiction. $\quad \square$

Is the above correct?

Comment: I don't think you need locally compact Hausdorff. _Any_ $\sigma$-compact space is automatically Lindelöf. That's the biggest complaint I can find, though.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. You are right it is for the converse that we need the locally compact Hausdorff assumption.

Comment: FYI. $\Omega=\omega_1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every closed subspace of an ordinal space is homeomorphic to an ordinal, and it is compact if and only if it is isomorphic to a successor ordinal.

It follows, therefore, that every compact subspace of $\omega_1$ is countable. Since a countable union of countable sets is countable, $\omega_1$ cannot be $\sigma$-compact.

(Do note that we are using the axiom of choice, as one expects when doing topology.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you comment if my proof has any flaws as well?

Comment: As Arthur said, any $\sigma$-compact space is Lindelöf, other than this, the proof seems fine. (Although more roundabout than the argument I offered.)

Comment: @bof: No need to guess. I can make mistakes as often as I'd like!